# Do Google Analytics delay until they are shown in the webview

Tags: events, google-analytics

I am tracking several google analytics in my app and it recognized that it takes some time until they are shown in the GA Frontend.

Do you know if this is normal or if they are stuck somewhere?

Is there any possibility to debug this? The events are sent out successfully (HTTP 200).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely normal for there to be a delay. It can be as long as 24-48 hours. The larger the amount of data that has to be processed for the profile the longer it takes, in my experience.